# Creating WMF file from Java BufferedImage

Tags: java, image, wmf

I have a requirement to export an image(typically, `java.awt.image.BufferedImage`) to WMF format (Windows Meta File). I have googled about an hour but no chance.

Do you know any library or recommendation to get it done?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

According to Apache FOP(https://xmlgraphics.apache.org/fop/1.1/graphics.html#wmf) :

"Windows Metafiles (WMF) are supported through classes in Apache Batik. At the moment, support for this format is experimental and may not always work as expected."

http://xmlgraphics.apache.org/batik/

Actually I found solutions to transcode FROM wmf, apparently nobody wants to create wmf, still you can give it a try.

Comment: Thank you @eldo. Do you have an idea why nobody wants to create wmf files?

Comment: Ok, As far as I get into the subject deeper, WMF is an interim format Windows OS is using when _copying_ and then _pasting_ objects. It has a set of commands (why it is so called a **meta file**). It might be fair not to export or create pyhsical WMF file in most cases, because there is a clipboard metaphor accessible. I would think it is useful when serializing the instant copies over the machines easily, especially Windows ones.

Answer (score -1):

Finally, I have found a library called `FreeHep` available on http://java.freehep.org/ . There are `EMF` and `Postscript` drivers alongside the core IO library. Creating a `VectorGraphics` object and drawing the `java.awt.image.BufferedImage` on that graphics object is very straightforward. The next step is completing the exporting process.